# insert a new line with information in C copy the other data

Tags: excel, vba

In column C I have the locations of the part numbers what I need to do is for each location separated by coma is to insert a new line with the location and same part number and description that goes with it. can

BEFORE:

```
A                 B             c
Part number  Description     Location

12456           black       c1, c2, c5
98745           blue        c10, r6, ic4, g6, h3
```

What I want

```
a                 B             C

123456         black          c1
123456         black          c2
123456         black          c5
98745          blue           c10
98745          blue           r6
98745          blue           ic4
98745          blue           g6
98745          blue           h3
```

Comment: This is a perfect task for `Power Query` if you want to avoid VBA > Load your data into PQ > Select column C > Split Column > On delimiter (comma obviously) > Advanced > Rows > OK. That's the free late cyber monday tip. If you do want to go with VBA, please include your code and tell us where you got stuck =)

Comment: Prefect thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub getdata()  

Dim data_count As Integer  
Dim Outputdata_count As Integer  
Dim part_number As Long  
Dim description As String  
Dim location As String  
Dim arr_location As Variant    
Dim loop_i As Integer  
Dim loop_d As Integer  

data_count = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For loop_i = 2 To data_count

     part_number = Cells(loop_i, "A")
     description = Cells(loop_i, "B")
     location = Cells(loop_i, "C")
     arr_location = Split(location, ",")

    For loop_d = LBound(arr_location) To UBound(arr_location)        
        Outputdata_count = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Cells(Outputdata_count, "D") = part_number
        Cells(Outputdata_count, "E") = description
        Cells(Outputdata_count, "F") = Trim(arr_location(loop_d))    
    Next loop_d

Next loop_i

End Sub
```